# h:inputText between p:selectManyCheckbox items

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectmanycheckbox

Is it possible, on some way, to display an h:inputText between the selectItems of a p:selectManyCheckbox?

What I'd like to have is:

- checkbox1
- checkbox2
- inputTextIfCheckbox2IsMarked (disabled if not marked..)
- checkbox 3
- checkbox 4

I know how to do the enable/disable etc of the checkbox, but outside of the selectItems. I'd like to put it between them.

Is that possible on SOME way?

My solution is (with the inputText not between the selectItems):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:selectManyCheckbox converter="otherAdmissionReasonConverter"
                          id="otherAdmissionReasonCheckbox"
                          value="#{potentialDonorFileBackingBean.potentialDonorFile.generalPatientInformation.otherAdmissionReasons}"
                          layout="grid" columns="1">

        <f:selectItems value="#{patientInformationBackingBean.otherAdmissionReasons}"
                       var="otherAdmissionReason"
                       itemValue="#{otherAdmissionReason}"
                       itemLabel="#{msgs['ar.'.concat(otherAdmissionReason)]}"/>
        <p:ajax update="customAdmissionReasonGrid"/>
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>

    <h:panelGroup id="customAdmissionReasonGrid"
                  styleClass="customAdmissionReason">

        <p:inputText id="customAdmissionReason"
                     disabled="#{!potentialDonorFileBackingBean.potentialDonorFile.generalPatientInformation.otherAdmissionReasonChecked()}"
                     value="#{potentialDonorFileBackingBean.potentialDonorFile.generalPatientInformation.customAdmissionReason}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
```

PrimeFaces: 5.2

Answer (score 3):

For PrimeFaces < 5.2.3 you can't. For PrimeFaces >=5.2.3 you can use a [custom layout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml) like this (© PrimeFaces)

```
<h3>Custom Layout (since v5.2.3)</h3>
<p:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="custom" value="#{checkboxView.selectedConsoles2}" layout="custom">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Xbox SixSixSix" itemValue="Xbox SixSixSix" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PS9" itemValue="PS9" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Wii Them" itemValue="Wii Them" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>

    <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
                <h:outputLabel for="opt1" value="Xbox SixSixSix" style="display:block"/>
                <p:checkbox id="opt1" for="custom" itemIndex="0" />
            </div>
            Some Custom Text between item 1 and 2
            <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
                <h:outputLabel for="opt2" value="PS9" style="display:block"/>
                <p:checkbox id="opt2" for="custom" itemIndex="1" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
                <h:outputLabel for="opt3" value="Wii Them" style="display:block"/>
                <p:checkbox id="opt3" for="custom" itemIndex="2" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p:outputPanel>
```